# Importing and displaying component from another local project in vue 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, primevue

I'm trying to create a library (vue3-lib) with vue3 and typescript based on primevue, that will be used in some other projects (like vue3-project). When running the vue3-lib everything works as expected, but when I'm running (npm run serve) the vue3-project I can't display the imported component from vue3-lib (I'm getting "[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: Symbol(Fragment) (symbol)" when accessing the Prime Test view).
I'm just starting vue3 and the whole ecosystem, so any advice would help. Thanks!

Github:
https://github.com/aitudor/vue3-lib
https://github.com/aitudor/vue3-project

Comment: It is likely that the issue stems from two separate instances of the vue package being used to start your application and one of its dependencies. Vue 3 uses `Symbol`s for some rendering work and although they _look_ the same (i.e. upon debugging, `Symbol(Fragment)` seems to be evaluated against `Symbol(Fragment)` which one could expect to match), they are not when they come from two different scripts. I’m facing the same issue as you and I don’t have a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Facing the same error and have no clue. :(

Comment: I haven't found a solution for this issue. What I did was to use git submodule and add the vue3-lib as a git submodule in vue3-project. This of course has some drawbacks, but this is where I am at. When I'll have more time, I'll try to figure out WHY this doesn't work. Thanks to all that responded.

Comment: I still don't know why this issue happens. I did find that building the component library using `render()` functions as opposed to using `<template>` for the markup seems to make things work fine again.

Comment: Did someone solves this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// main.js
import * as vue from "vue";
window.Vue = vue;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please refrain from code-only answers. In this case, you might explain why the OP received the error and how this solves it.